# Adding arguments to Django include('django.contrib.auth.urls')

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I am trying to add an additional argument to my Django default password reset which is
mysite.com/password_reset.

I am trying to make it look like: mysite.com/user/password_reset.Right now I am using this method:

Code for home.html(Contains password change link)

```
<li><a href="{% url 'password_reset' user.username %}">Change Password</a></li>
```

My app/urls.py:

```
path('<str:username>/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

This is the Error I am getting:

```
NoReverseMatch at /test3-b
Reverse for 'password_reset' with arguments '('test3-b',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['password_reset/$']
```

Comment: It seems correct. The problem might be related with the argument you're passing. Can you share where is `user.username` coming from?

Comment: It is coming from the request method I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing something like this:

```
<li>
<a href="{% url 'password_reset' username=request.user.username %}">Change Password</a>
</li>
```